# Mexican citizen flying to Canada via USA

Tags: usa, canada, transit-visas, mexican-citizens

I am a Mexican citizen wanting to travel to Canada. The only flights I can find have two layovers in the USA. Is it possible to make the trip?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You need a [transit visa](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/other/transit.html).

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie or a B visa or a border crossing card.

Comment: Can you use a C for *two* layovers?

Comment: @chx: Yes, you can even leave the airport to go by ground to another airport or to another mode of transportation to leave the US. It just needs to be a reasonably immediate and continuous transit. The regulations only say that it cannot exceed 29 days.

Comment: There are non-stop flights from Mexico City to Toronto, Vancouver, Calgary and Montreal (maybe others), so it's certainly possible to get from Mexico to Canada without entering the US.

Comment: @chx you can even use a US transit visa to *drive* from Mexico to Canada.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan a route that has stops in the United States, you would need to [apply for a transit visa](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/other/transit.html), unless you already have a valid visitor (B) visa.

> Generally, a citizen of a foreign country who wishes to enter the United States must first obtain a visa, either a nonimmigrant visa for temporary stay, or an immigrant visa for permanent residence. Transit (C) visas are nonimmigrant visas for persons traveling in immediate and continuous transit through the United States en route to another country, with few exceptions. Immediate and continuous transit is defined as a reasonably expeditious departure of the traveler in the normal course of travel as the elements permit and assumes a prearranged itinerary without any unreasonable layover privileges.

Currently, the [visa wait time](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/wait-times.html) in Mexico City, for example, is 3 days, 7 days at Tijuana TPF, Hermosillo is 1 day.

You may be looking at those flights as they're less expensive than those that are non-stop. However, when you factor in the visa application fee of $160 and the US visa application requirements, it may be more cost- and time-effective to book a direct flight from Mexico to Canada.

Comment: Since a Mexican national will generally [get a 10-year visa](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/fees/reciprocity-by-country/MX.html), it probably makes sense in most cases to apply for a visitor (B) visa instead of a transit (C) visa. For those living near the US border, it may also make more sense to apply for a [border crossing card](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/border-crossing-card.html), which costs the same, is also valid for 10 years, and allows the holder to make quick trips across the border without a passport, but serves as a B visa when used with a passport.